# What could be the cause of RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting this exception on my tomcat server (+liferay)

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
```

my class is like that :

```
public class SingleExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  public SingleExecutor(){
    super(1, 1,0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if(command instanceof AccessLogInsert){
        AccessLogInsert ali = (AccessLogInsert)command;
        ali.setConn(conn);
        ali.setPs(ps);
    }
    super.execute(command);
  }
}
```

I get this exception on the line `super.execute(command);`
This error can occur when the queue is full but the `LinkedBlockingQueue` size is 2^31, and  I am sure that there is no so many command waiting.

At start everything is stable, but after I redeploy a war it starts occuring. This class is not part of the war but in a jar in tomcat/lib.

Do you have any idea why this happend and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

From [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) JavaDoc (emphasis mine)

> New tasks submitted in method `execute(java.lang.Runnable)` will be rejected **when the `Executor` has been shut down**, and also when the `Executor` uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, and is saturated. In either case, the execute method invokes the `RejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(java.lang.Runnable, java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor)` method of its `RejectedExecutionHandler`. Four predefined handler policies are provided:
>
> 1. In the default `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy`, the handler throws a runtime `RejectedExecutionException` upon rejection.
> 2. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the thread that invokes execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted.
> 3. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy`, a task that cannot be executed is simply dropped.
> 4. In `ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy`, if the executor is not shut down, the task at the head of the work queue is dropped, and then execution is retried (which can fail again, causing this to be repeated.)
>
> It is possible to define and use other kinds of `RejectedExecutionHandler` classes. Doing so requires some care especially when policies are designed to work only under particular capacity or queuing policies.

Presumably therefore, reloading the war triggers a shutdown of the `Executor`. Try putting the relevant libraries in the war, so that Tomcat's `ClassLoader` has a better chance of correctly reloading your app.

Comment: Last part of the answer is nice one.

Comment: **"New tasks submitted in method `execute(java.lang.Runnable)` will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down."** This gave rise to a bug in my code, which I resolved by sleeping the thread for 500ms after shutdown (which may not be necessary), then setting the scheduler to `null`, so that next time a task needs to be run, the method in question checks to see if the scheduler is `null`. If it is, a new one is created. Thus the rejection for the reason of a shutdown is eliminated.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief sleeping is not necessary, but proper concurrency control is. Further, while your “solution” may stop crashes, it’s just hiding what sounds like a big resource ownership problem.

Comment: @OrangeDog very nicely explained. But suppose it never happens to my app after proper testing. Happened just once in production. Can it be caused by some other external factor like DB server down or Kafka server issue. Is increasing max-pool and queue capacity  a solution to this?

Answer (score 20):

Just to add to OrangeDog's excellent answer, the contract of an `Executor` is indeed such that its `execute` method will throw `RejectedExecutionException` when the executor is saturated (i.e. there is no space in the queue).

However, it would have been useful if it **blocked** instead, automatically waiting until there is space in the queue for the new task.

With the following custom `BlockingQueue` it's possible to achieve that:

```
public final class ThreadPoolQueue extends ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> {

    public ThreadPoolQueue(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
        try {
            put(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

That essentially implements the backpressure algorithm, slowing the producer whenever the executor saturates.

Use it as:

```
int n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, n, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new ThreadPoolQueue(n));
for (Runnable task : tasks) {
    executor.execute(task); // will never throw, nor will queue more than n tasks
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: `CallerRunsPolicy` already exists in order to achieve this, and gives better throughput than simply blocking.

Comment: No it doesn't because blocking the producer by letting it run a task is a pessimization; it will starve the pool while the producer is busy with that single task.

Comment: This conversation is the best part of this page. rustyx is right telling that it's a "pessimization". I would say considering the problem at hand the solution should be one of the 2 above. `CallerRunsPolicy` does exist and is cheap to use. If it really leads to the pool starving, one might be better off implementing blocking.